# How to use HashMap with List<Number>

Tags: java, list, arraylist, numbers, hashmap

How do I correctly instantiate a `HashMap` whose values are variants of `List<Number>` - i.e., the values could take the form of `List<Long>` and/or `List<Double>`. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
HashMap<String, List<Number>> foo = new HashMap<String, List<Number>>();
foo.put("Tenticles", new ArrayList<Long>());
```

The error message: `The method put(String, List<Number>) ... is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<Long>)`.

I also want to be able to add a `Long` to a constituent `List<Long>` and likewise with any `Double`.

***EDIT*** These answers don't show how to add a `Long` or a `Double` to one of the constituent lists.

Comment: This is going to be tricky to do if you can make it work at all, because the covariance stuff will get messy.  You could totally make it work, though, with `foo.put("Tenticles", new ArrayList<Number>())`, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a wildcard

```
HashMap<String, List<? extends Number>> foo = new HashMap<String, List<? extends Number>>();
LinkedList<Long> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(10L);
foo.put("Tenticles", list);
```

Your `List` objects now must be a sub-type of `Number`.

Comment: How do I then add something to the arraylist that go inside

Comment: @user2763361 Just keep a reference to the `List` and call its `add` method with the element you want to add. You can always retrieve the `List` with `get(int)`.

Comment: It doesn't work. `The method add(capture#7-of ?) in the type ... not applicable for the arguments long`.

Comment: @user Please update your question with how you are trying to use it. It works fine for me.

Comment: `foo.get("Tenticles").add(10L)`.

Comment: @user2763361 Ah in that case yeah, you can't add anything to it because you don't know the type of the list your retrieve. You need to add them before. You can also keep the reference and to it after you've added it to the list. It's the same object after all.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `wildcards`

e.g.

```
Map<String, List<? extends Number>> foo = new HashMap<String, List<? extends Number>>();
```

If you are using Java 7, you can do the following to avoid some duplication

```
Map<String, List<? extends Number>> foo = new HashMap<>();
```

To add an item to the List

```
List<Long> longs= new ArrayList<>();
longs.add(10L);
foo.put("numbers", longs);
```

Comment: How do I then add something to the arraylist that go inside

Comment: You can do it a number of ways. Here is an exmaple:
List<Long> longs = new ArrayList<>();
 longs.add(10L);
 List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<>();
 doubles.add(23.20);
 List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
 numbers.addAll(longs);
 numbers.addAll(doubles);
 foo.put("numbers", numbers);

I apologize for the formatting. :P

Comment: The answer now contains an example of adding elements to the list contained in the Map

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do:-

```
    final HashMap<String, List<? extends Number>> foo = new HashMap<>();
    foo.put( "Tenticles", new ArrayList<Long>() );
```

The syntax `List<? extends Number>` means a list of objects where each object implements `Number`.

Comment: How do I then add something to this arraylist? It's not working :s